# Law of Iterated Expectation Proof

Tags: statistics

I have a proof that needs to be done:

$$
\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y|X)\,X]
$$

So I start with the following
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(XY) &= \mathbb{E}(X)\cdot\mathbb{E}(Y)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(X)\cdot\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y|X)\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(Y|X)\,X]
\end{align}

Is this correct or am I making some error?

Comment: Your first step is in error:  $\mathbb E[XY] = \mathbb E[X] \mathbb E[Y]$ in general only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  But if they were independent, then there is no point in the statement that needs proving.

Comment: Use $E((XY|X)=XE(Y|X)$ and iterated law of expectation on $E(XY)$ by conditional on $X$ first.